# маленькое окно с кнопками поверх канвы

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр

Допустим игра отрисовывается на канве, при поражении хочу вывести окошко с результатом и кнопкой продолжить , какие есть варианты ? Вывести отдельный fragment? можно ли так? Или новое активити сверстанное так чтобы выглядело как окошко?   Вроде есть еще диалоговое окно, но можно ли его сверстать до какого угодно вида и выводить поверх канвы?

```
    public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
//тут создается поток в котором реализован игровой цикл, при некотором положении в игровом цикле хочу вызвать диалог, но так как наследуюсь не от Activity сделать это не получается.. как быть?
}
```

Вот так вызываю диалог

```
new GameOverFragment().show(getFragmentManager(),"login");
```

Проблема точно такая же как и тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268422/show-dialog-in-game-with-canvas
но я не понял как её они там решили..

Answer (score 1):

Canvas находится в каком-то определенном месте интерфейса и никак не влияет на весь остальной интерфейс. Вы можете диалог показать любым удобным способом: [диалоговое окно](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), новый фрагмент, или сделать visible уже существующие элемент интерфейса, расположенный поверх.

Comment: Я понял, для  меня сейчас важно сделать это окно например круглым, со своим фоном, со своей формой кнопок . Что используется для того , чтобы приводить к такому виду интерфейс ?  DialogFragment со своей разметкой?

Comment: все круглое - это на самом деле квадратное с прозрачным фоном по углам. :) вы можете показать картинку с изображением вашего круглого интерфейса, и обработать касание через с помощью onTouchEvent(). можете сделать собственный класс с круглыми кнопками (подсказка: кнопка - это TextView с добавленным фоном, вы можете сделать свой).

Comment: я даже диалог не могу показать поверх канвы...не могу вызвать его . сейчас приложу код класса с которого хочу его вызвать.